# Sharepoint 2013 как получить значение выпадающего списка?

Tags: jquery

В элементе списка Sharepoint 2013 есть combobox с 5-ю значениями.
Задача: в переменную получить , то значение , которое выбрано в выпадающем списке.
Для выполнения задачи использовать Jquery.
Вот мой код (пытался сделать 4-мя способами, но все они выдают либо пустое либо undefind значение)

```
`<script src="/bz/SiteAssets/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
 function Flag() {
  var r=$("input[Title='Status']").val()
  alert(r);

 var rr = jQuery("select[title='Status'] option:selected").text();
 alert(rr);

 var rrr = jQuery('input[title="Status"]').val();
 alert(rrr);

 var rrrr=$("input[Title*='Opportunity ID']").val()
 alert (rrrr);
 }

 </script>
 <input onclick="Flag()" type="button" value="Первая кнопка"/>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вот так, но только после того как выставил признак Combobox "необязательно должен содержать данные"
var Value = $("select[title='Status'] option:selected").text();